# How to trim a mp4 video in a Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to trim a MP4 video in a Windows Phone 8 Application.

Say when saving a video, I only want to save the last two minutes.
I have tried converting the video stream into a byte array and altering it. Since the mp4 format has headers and lot of other metadata it is not easy to achieve this fiddling with the byte array of the stream.

If it is a Windows Store app I can use MediaTranscode class in the Windows.Media.Transcoding API to achieve this like in the article below.

[Trim Video Windows Store App Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868176.aspx)

I pretty much want to do something similar in windows phone.

Is there a similar API I can use in WP?

I also have been looking into Microsoft Media Foundation to achieve this? I am no C++ expert and wanting achieve this in C#.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So, with what Nokia just released, you'll have some sort of answer soon. (Nokia Video Trimmer.)

Comment: Any ideas when or IF nokia is releasing a Video Editing/Transcoding SDK to accompany their imaging one?

Answer (score 1):

C# in general is not setup to do movie editing. It's older sibling c++ is where this done. I know that's not the answer you want to hear but sometimes that's the only reality there is. I was going to offer a hack to make it happen but after digging through the MSDN libraries I don't even see a worthy hack for this.

Find a C++ example and work from there. It will be a little headache but you are much better off than attempting to make C# bend beyond its elasticity point.

Here is a similar thread expressing your concerns.

http://forums.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-apps/204490-video-editing-apps.html

They have made the point that there isn't a single video editing tool on the entire market.
With how long the market has been around I would assume this is because it's not a capability in C#. Which happens to be 99% of the developers working on windows phone right now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AMR. Yeah it is unforunate that there is not much support for this. Specially on the mobile platform. Nokia folks have done an app to trim videos. Exactly what i want to do. [Nokia Video Trimmer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-video-trimmer/50ece96d-bb5d-4669-a7e1-37246d904d5c)